# Why running DFA takes linear time?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, theory, dfa

I just start learning automata. It seems easy to understand given DFA and not too difficult to design one. But I feel it's very hard to prove things...

Can anyone give a informal proof for this question or some hint? Thanks a lot!

PS: sorry I didn't phrase very clearly.  What @Dan said is exactly what I mean:

> why deciding the question "Given a string w. Does the automaton accept
>   or reject w?" can be done in linear time?

Comment: Linear in what? Please make your question a lot more descriptive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to know why deciding the question "Given a string w. Does the automaton accept or reject w?" can be done in linear time?

Suppose w=a_1...a_n. Start in the initial state q_0 and apply the transition \delta(q_0, a_1) = q_1, which brings you to q_1. Now, repeat this n times untill you processed the last letter. That's a linear time algorithm ;)

Comment: Wow, very detailed explanation! Thanks!

Comment: I should add that this is true if the input alphabet is not part of the decision problem ;)

Comment: Also you need to be able to look up the transition for every pair (q, a) in O(1).

Comment: Only if the input alphabe size is not part of the input to the decision problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try thinking about it this way:

1. How many times is each character in the input string read by the DFA?
2. How much work does the DFA do when processing a single character from the input?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Suppose the input length is n, then I think the answer is O(n).  Therefore it's linear right? Thanks~!

Comment: @Arch1tect - O(n) is just a different way of saying it's linear. The O denotes an asymptotic upper bound - it's a formal mathematical notation that's not specific to computer science. [See here for more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: @Steve314 Linear is a way of saying the function is Theta(n), which is a bit more.

Comment: @Khaur - I didn't really mean specifically big-O, but that's certainly what I said - oops. Any of the asymptotic bounds can be called linear so long as they are `?(n)` (replace the `?` as needed). But you're right that the within-a-constant-factor Theta(n) makes more sense if you're just saying "linear" without saying which bound.